# AttributeError: type object 'Graph' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, igraph

I am using python-igraph.

Running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2':[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]}
ct = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
from igraph import Graph, plot
g = Graph.DataFrame(edges=ct)
layout = g.layout('tree')
plot(g, layout = layout)
```

It throws rhis error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-fc1ba82e7692> in <module>
      1 from igraph import *
----> 2 g = Graph.DataFrame(edges=ct)
      3 layout = g.layout('tree')
      4 plot(g, layout = layout)

AttributeError: type object 'Graph' has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

But in the [documentation of python-igraph](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-pysrc.html#Graph.DataFrame), DataFrame function is implemented. I am not sure why this error appears then. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is a bit newer than what is already implemented. A new release is due to appear in the coming week, that functionality will then become available.